# How do I stack images vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css, masonry, jquery-isotope

[image]

I tried many times and they always have a set horizontal line to seperate them that I can't get through (like in google search)

my css

```
#gallery{
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;

}
#gallery img{
  max-width: 100%;
  align-self: flex-end;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I've tried adding flex grow and shrink to be 1, once i change the flex wrap to nowrap they just inflate to full size

I want to ultimately use this method to show the index images here
http://setch.me/

Comment: [masonry.js](https://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: try this link https://codepen.io/AdamBlum/pen/fwrnE

Comment: @krim, please show your attempts (HTML and CSS) so the community can point out where you're wrong and guide you to the right direction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only way you can achieve the image stacking is using a Javascript.

There's two Javascript libraries that does the magic for you.

- [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/)
- [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Comment: [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16581376): You should not add tags to a question related to an _approach of your answer_. Though the typo fixes were actually OK, I also reverted them because IMO, the question another issue: what has to topic owner tried so far (markup, CSS, libraries, etc.). A question should be based an that.

Comment: Beside from that, you should [not post links only, but show how to use those libraries/frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @try-catch-finally the link posted contains enough information and **How tos** better than anyone can generate.

Comment: Please read [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) and [Should I flag answers which contain only a link as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer). And now let's stop this meta discussion.